# HTML formatted email does not display correctly

Tags: php

I'm still struggling with this mail script - I'm now getting all the marked up html through rather than seeing it as rendered html if that makes sense?

```
<?php
$mailheader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$mailHeader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$formcontent .="<table border='1'>";
foreach ($_POST as $field=>$value)
{
    $formcontent.="<tr>";
    $formcontent .= "<td>$field:</td> <td>$value</td>";
    $formcontent.="</tr>";
}
$formcontent .= '<tr><td>User-Agent: </td><td>'.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].'</td>';
$formcontent .="</table>";


$recipient = "info@*******.com";
$subject = "Event feedback form";
$mailheader = "From: web.form@*******-events.co.uk\r\n";
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";
$mailHeader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";


mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Failure!");
header("location:http://www.******-events.co.uk");
?>
```

Comment: How are you opening the page? Are you dragging it onto your browser window/ opening it through the file? Or are you browsing to it using localhost/index.php ? (Assuming you're hosting it locally at the moment)

Answer (score 1):

Follow php's documentation:

You'll need html tags

```
 <?php
// multiple recipients
$to  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= 'wez@example.com';

// subject
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

// message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: Thats the thing - I'm putting all those headers in but still the email form returns this:

    <table border='1'><tr><td>Company::</td> <td>test</td></tr>  
    <tr>td>Contact::</td> <td>jim holmes</td></tr><tr><td>Email::</td>         
    <td>test</td></tr><tr><td>Date::</td> <td>221122</td></tr><tr>
    <td>Was_pre_event_support_thorough?:</td> <td>5</td></tr><tr>
    <td>Enough_pre_event_support?:</td> <td>5</td></tr><tr>
    <td>Good_communication_throughout?:</td> <td>5</td></tr><tr>  

etc, you get the idea.. why isn't the email client rendering the html?

Comment: it doesn't say you put them in there in your php file. where are you thinking they're included?

Comment: The first three lines?

    <?php
    $mailheader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $mailHeader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-    
    1\r\n";

Comment: that doesn't do the same thing. try doing it the same way the example does. place the html tags inside the message string.

Comment: But i don't have a message string in my script? This is coming from an online form that I want formatted into a table - if I paste the resulting html into an html doc it works fine - just not in the email client!

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use a PHP class as PHPMailer for HTML emails. And btw I will add the full HTML document tags (html, head, body, etc...) for the mail body.

Answer (score 0):

I'd missed these:

```
$formcontent = '<html><body>';
```

Thanks for everyone's time and input though
Jim